# In jQuery drag and drop how can I identify a source element and change it's color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The code below copies (drag and drop) an li from one column to another keeping the original li in place. I am trying color the orginal li, in the orginal column, after the copy so I know which I have used.

This line will find a hardcoded ID in the source column and change it's color but I can't figure out how to make 'input1' a variable so it can be used on any selected line.

```
       $(ident).parent().find('#input1').addClass('highlight');
```

I have also tried variations with 'event.srcElement' but can't select just one line with a variable.

My Code:

```
      $( "#available > li" ).draggable({ 
           revert: 'invalid'
           connectToSortable: '#selected',
           containment: '#drag_container',
           helper: 'clone',
           start: function(ui, event) {
             dragged = $(this).attr('id');
             draggedx = $(this).attr('class');
           }
       });

      $( "#selected" ).droppable({
           drop: function(event, ui) {
          var ident = "#" +  dragged;

          $(ident).parent().find('.classname').addClass('highlight');

          $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo( this );
          }
       });
```

HTML:

`<li id="item1" class="lineclass"><input type="text" id="input1"
              class="classname" name=\"1" value="Item 1"></li>
        <li id="item2" class="lineclass"><input type="text" id="input2"
              class="classname" name=\"2" value="Item 2"></li>

      </pre>`

CSS:
           .highlight{background-color: yellow;font-color:green;}

edit - i'm trying to fix the html formatting

Comment: how is `#input1` constructed? you can replace the `.find('#string')` and look up it earlier via javascript to produce something you allready did for the other element, like `dragged` or `ident`

Comment: That's what I can't figure out - the code to grab  the id.